# How change Searchable Spinner list background color in android?

Tags: android, search, automation, android-spinner

I wanted a Searchable Spinner in android. i did it by this activity_main.xml code

```
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/search_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

And the MainActivity.java code is

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SearchableSpinner searchableSpinner = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.search_spinner);
        String[] items = new String[] { "A Tea", "B Tea", "C Tea", "D Tea", "E Tea"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinnerlist,R.id.item ,items);
        searchableSpinner.setTitle("Select Item");
        searchableSpinner.setPositiveButton("Cancel");
        searchableSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        searchableSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my spinnerlis.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#C79329"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="name"
        android:background="#C79329"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But my spinner list is white now. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: android:textColor="#FFF"

you set your text color white   try to change it 

and try first to use Simple adapter 
if it works then problem in your XML

if it dont then problem in your code

Comment: your code is working fine for me

Comment: Thanks @Elsunhoty  and sravs this code is working fine for me too. But spinner dropdown list is white now. i 
 want change spinner dropdown list background color.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your styles.xml and add in your theme the following item line.

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.SpinnerDialog</item>
```

Your style theme will look like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.SpinnerDialog</item>
</style>
```

After, create this style

```
<style name="AppTheme.SpinnerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
     <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
</style>
```

This worked for me